# CodeIgniter and dependancy injection / Controller injection

Tags: php, codeigniter, dependency-injection

I would like to be able to do controller injection with codeigniter. Is there a library that changes the core controller file for it?

My use would be something like this (pseudo):

**Factory file // declares all dependencies that will occur**

```
if ( Controller == "Navigation" ) { 
    new Navigation( new PageRepository() ); 
}
else{
    new Navigation(); 
}
```

**Navigation Controller file**

```
class Navigation extends MX_Controller {

    private $repository;

    public function __Construct( IPageRepository $repo )
    {
        parent::__Construct();
        $this->repository = $repo;
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $data[ "model" ] = $this->repository->GetAllPages();
        $this->load->view( 'index', $data );
    }
}
```

Anyone have a clue about dependency injection in any other way? I would like to implement it for unit testing!

Answer (score -1):

Not really sure if I understand what you're trying to achieve here, but if you want to modify/extend the core of CodeIgniter you should use *hooks*.

Here's a link to the docs, check out if there is a hook point you can use:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html